# How to connect WPA2-Enterprise authentication network in window application?

Tags: c#, wifi, wpa

I have created wifi scanner in .net c# window application. Right now i'm able to connect to WPA2-Personal authentication network.Now i want to connect with WPA-Enterprise Network but i'm not getting any idea how to connect to it.
Please if you have any solution so let me know

Below is my code for WPA2-Personal which is working

```
        WlanClient client = new WlanClient();
        foreach (WlanClient.WlanInterface wlanIface in client.Interfaces)
        {
            Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork[] networks = wlanIface.GetAvailableNetworkList(0);
            foreach (Wlan.WlanAvailableNetwork network in networks)
            {
                Wlan.Dot11Ssid ssid = network.dot11Ssid;
                string networkName = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(ssid.SSID, 0, (int)ssid.SSIDLength);

                ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(networkName);
                item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultCipherAlgorithm.ToString());
                item.SubItems.Add(network.wlanSignalQuality + "%");
                item.SubItems.Add(network.dot11DefaultAuthAlgorithm.ToString());
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            }


            string profileName = "Network"; // this is also the SSID
            string macA = "MAC_ADDRESS";
            string key = "PASSWORD";                
            string  profileXml = string.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"US-ASCII\"?><WLANProfile xmlns=\"http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WLAN/profile/v1\"><name>{0}</name><SSIDConfig><SSID><name>{0}</name></SSID></SSIDConfig><connectionType>ESS</connectionType><connectionMode>auto</connectionMode><autoSwitch>false</autoSwitch><MSM><security><authEncryption><authentication>WPAPSK</authentication><encryption>TKIP</encryption><useOneX>false</useOneX></authEncryption><sharedKey><keyType>passPhrase</keyType><protected>false</protected><keyMaterial>{1}</keyMaterial></sharedKey></security></MSM></WLANProfile>", profileName, key); //WPA-PSK
            wlanIface.SetProfile(Wlan.WlanProfileFlags.AllUser, profileXml, true);

            wlanIface.Connect(Wlan.WlanConnectionMode.Profile, Wlan.Dot11BssType.Any, profileName);
        }
```